# Wordpress plugin ajax post parameter

Tags: plugins, jquery, ajax

i have problem.
I don't know why but my paramters from form don't pass too aad_process_ajax().

My code from functions and jquery:

Function with my form:

```
function aad_render_admin() {

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php _e('Admin Ajax Demo', 'aad'); ?></h2>
            <div class="wrap">
        <form id="aad-form" action="" method="POST">
            <div>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="header" />
<input type="text" name="body" />
<input type="text" name="urls" />
                <input type="submit" name="aad-submit" id="aad_submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Get Results', 'aad'); ?>"/>
                <img src="<?php echo admin_url('/images/wpspin_light.gif'); ?>" class="waiting" id="aad_loading" style="display:none;"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="aad_results"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#aad-form').submit(function() {
        $('#aad_loading').show();
        $('#aad_submit').attr('disabled', true);

      data = {
          action: 'aad_get_results',
          aad_nonce: aad_vars.aad_nonce
      };

         $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            $('#aad_results').html(response);
            $('#aad_loading').hide();
            $('#aad_submit').attr('disabled', false);
        });    

        return false;
    });
});
```

And this function don't get my parameters why?

```
function aad_process_ajax() {
    global $wpdb;

    echo $name = $_POST['name'];
    $header = $_POST['header'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $urls = $_POST['urls'];
    echo 'xxxx';

        $wpdb->insert(  
        'wp_myprojects',
            array(    'name' => $name,
                    'header' => $header,
                    'body' => $body,
                    'urls' => $urls,
                    ),
            array(    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s',
                    '%s'
                    )
        );

    $wpdb->show_errors();
    /*EVRY PROCESS AJAX MUST DIE!!!!*/
    die();
    /*EVRY PROCESS AJAX MUST DIE!!!!*/
}
add_action('wp_ajax_aad_get_results','aad_process_ajax');
```

Tell my why parameters don't show in function `aad_process_ajax()`.

Problem is in Jquery or Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery code

```
 data = {
      action: 'aad_get_results',
      aad_nonce: aad_vars.aad_nonce
  };
```

you are passing only `action` and `aad_nonce`, you are **not** passing form data.

If you want pass variables, you ave to pass it with ajax, use something like:

```
  data = {
      action: 'aad_get_results',
      aad_nonce: aad_vars.aad_nonce,
      form_data: $('#aad-form').serialize()
  };
```

After that, in your `aad_process_ajax` function use:

```
function aad_process_ajax() {

  parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $form_data);
  $name = isset($form_data['name']) ? : '';
  $header = isset($form_data['header']) ? : '';
  $body = isset($form_data['body']) ? : '';
  $urls = isset($form_data['urls']) ? : '';

  // the rest of your code here

}
```

Comment: when i call echo $name = isset($form_data['name']) ? : ''; I got 1? Edit: Ok Thx work thanks:)